# Sniff Wi-Fi network traffic

Tags: wifi, sniffing

With Airodump I can see Wi-Fi networks and clients associated to them. I know password to this Wi-Fi networks. Is it possible to dump encrypted traffic between AP and client (WPA2) and then decrypt it with password to see unencrypted traffic?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to sniff your traffic in Wireshark:

Edit --> Preferences --> Protocols --> IEEE 802.11 --> Decrypt --> Enter hexadecimal key.

Comment: I know how to decrypt but I don't know that way, thanks. I'm using Airdecap. I asked about technical capabilities to sniff all network traffic between AP and client. Is it possible?

Comment: I see, if you aren't performing this from on the client itself, I am not sure. Sorry!

Comment: I sniff some traffic to pcap file. But after decrypt via Airdecap I got file 24 bytes long and nothing in there.

Answer (score 0):

First, use [Airodump-ng's --output-format](http://linux-commands-examples.com/airodump-ng) to capture in pcap format.

The, use tshark, per [Decrypt WPA with Tshark on ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/24249/decrypt-wpa-with-tshark), or wireshark itself as 404Cat listed.

> tshark -nr input.pcap -o wlan.enable_decryption:TRUE -o "uat:80211_keys:\"wpa-pwd\",\" Passphrase:SSID\"" -R "http"